# TypeScript error Argument of type '(response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: void) => void | PromiseLike<void>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-типы

Всем привет!

Появилась проблема с typescript, не могу понять, что именно в типах не соотвествует:

"Argument of type '(response: IResponse) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: void) => void | PromiseLike'".

Проблема с функцией check().

Очень нужна помощь, идеи кончились. Заранее спасибо!

```html
interface IResponse {
    isChecked: boolean;
}
type TResponse = IResponse;

.....

function dispatchAsync<TResponsePayload>(dispatch: Dispatch, actionType: string, asyncCall: () => Promise<TResponsePayload>): any;

....

check = async () => {
        const {actions, param} = this.props;
        await actions.getInfoById(param.id).then(
            (response: IResponse) => {
                this.setState({isChecked: response.isChecked});
            }
        );
    };

.....

getInfoById = async (id: string): Promise<void> =>
        dispatchAsync<TPermission>(this.dispatch, CHECK_ACTION, async () => {
            return await this.service.getInfoById(id);
        });
```

Comment: У вас `getInfoById` возвращает `Promise<void>`, а в `check` вы от него ожидаете `IResponse`.